# SQLite INSERT OR IGNORE doesn't ignore duplicates

Tags: sqlite, insert

I'm writing a java program to combine two databases that have the same schema. This is an issue with SQLite or my queries, not the Java code as I was able to replicate this exactly in the DB Browser application.

I have 2 databases: One being merged, one being the destination.

I initially connect to the database being merged then ATTACH the destination database as "dest".
I issue the following query to copy the data:

```
INSERT or IGNORE into dest.AnalogInput SELECT * from AnalogInput where timestamp >= 1600824664131000000 AND timestamp <= 1600824664131000000
```

This works fine and inserts the data. If I run it again over the same data, it inserts a duplicate into the destination database. I thought the point of "OR IGNORE" was to prevent duplicates? Is my query incorrect or is my understanding of the OR IGNORE incorrect?

EDIT: yes I know the timestamps are the same - it is a general query and I'm just using a couple of samples on a single timestamp to test.

Thanks!

Comment: Are there any unique constraints in dest.AnalogInput?

Comment: No. The database is automatically generated by RTI DDS Recorder. The Create statement listed in DB Browser is: CREATE TABLE "AnalogInput" ("SampleInfo_source_timestamp" INTEGER,"machineId" INTEGER,"ioId" INTEGER,"value" REAL)

Comment: Then there is nothing to stop the insertions.

Comment: Can you add this after the fact to a database?

Comment: What I want is simply, if any insert combination of the 4 columns is already in the table, don't insert it.

Comment: Do the 2 tables have exactly the same columns?

Comment: Yes, exactly...

Comment: Check my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`INSERT OR IGNORE` works only when there are unique constraints in the table.
Since there aren't and you can't add any, because SQLite is not that flexible, the only way to do what you want is like this:

```
INSERT or IGNORE INTO dest.AnalogInput 
SELECT * FROM AnalogInput WHERE ....
EXCEPT
SELECT * FROM dest.AnalogInput
```

Comment: So if I were to somehow get the create statement changed, how would I structure the unique keyword to get the same results?

Comment: `create table ......, unique(col1, col2, .....)`. Since you want the combination of all the columns to be unique you must enumerate all the columns inside the parenthesis after the keyword UNIQUE.

Comment: Check also this: https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-unique-constraint/

Comment: And also nulls are not considered equal. So 2 rows with exactly the same values in all but 1 column and nulls in the other column could be inserted.